# pandas boxplot keyError when creating grouped boxplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a boxplot where I have Minutes in the X-axis and a quantity in Megabytes in the Y-axis. The data also has a quantity of Robots, which should be grouped per 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 robots and then boxplotted. I have tried a million ways, but this one seems like the one that should work due to its simplicity, but does not.

```
df = df[['Robots','TIME_MTD','MB']]
display(df)
ax = plt.axes()
df.groupby('Robots').boxplot(column='MB', by='TIME_MTD',ax=ax, subplots=False)
```

I get the following outputs

```
Robots  TIME_MTD        MB
0   10  0 days 00:00:00 1.40593
1   10  0 days 00:00:00 1.47922
2   10  0 days 00:00:00 1.52110
3   10  0 days 00:00:00 1.52110
4   10  0 days 00:00:00 1.59341
... ... ... ...
140739  5   0 days 00:14:00 6.43844
140740  5   0 days 00:14:00 6.53658
140741  5   0 days 00:14:00 6.59067
140742  5   0 days 00:14:00 6.65408
140743  5   0 days 00:15:00 6.70663

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_254513/3151890620.py in <module>
     23 display(df)
     24 ax = plt.axes()
---> 25 df.groupby('Robots').boxplot(column='MB', by='TIME_MTD',ax=ax, figsize=double, subplots=False)
     26 
     27 # display(df)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in boxplot_frame_groupby(grouped, subplots, column, fontsize, rot, grid, ax, figsize, layout, sharex, sharey, backend, **kwargs)
    602     """
    603     plot_backend = _get_plot_backend(backend)
--> 604     return plot_backend.boxplot_frame_groupby(
    605         grouped,
    606         subplots=subplots,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/boxplot.py in boxplot_frame_groupby(grouped, subplots, column, fontsize, rot, grid, ax, figsize, layout, sharex, sharey, **kwds)
    463             multi_key = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([keys, column])
    464             column = list(multi_key.values)
--> 465         ret = df.boxplot(
    466             column=column,
    467             fontsize=fontsize,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in boxplot_frame(self, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, backend, **kwargs)
    509 ):
    510     plot_backend = _get_plot_backend(backend)
--> 511     return plot_backend.boxplot_frame(
    512         self,
    513         column=column,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/boxplot.py in boxplot_frame(self, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, **kwds)
    392     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    393 
--> 394     ax = boxplot(
    395         self,
    396         column=column,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/boxplot.py in boxplot(data, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, **kwds)
    344         # Prefer array return type for 2-D plots to match the subplot layout
    345         # https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/12216#issuecomment-241175580
--> 346         result = _grouped_plot_by_column(
    347             plot_group,
    348             data,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/boxplot.py in _grouped_plot_by_column(plotf, data, columns, by, numeric_only, grid, figsize, ax, layout, return_type, **kwargs)
    205     **kwargs,
    206 ):
--> 207     grouped = data.groupby(by)
    208     if columns is None:
    209         if not isinstance(by, (list, tuple)):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, dropna)
   7624         # error: Argument "squeeze" to "DataFrameGroupBy" has incompatible type
   7625         # "Union[bool, NoDefault]"; expected "bool"
-> 7626         return DataFrameGroupBy(
   7627             obj=self,
   7628             keys=by,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in __init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, mutated, dropna)
    886             from pandas.core.groupby.grouper import get_grouper
    887 
--> 888             grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
    889                 obj,
    890                 keys,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py in get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate, dropna)
    858                 in_axis, level, gpr = False, gpr, None
    859             else:
--> 860                 raise KeyError(gpr)
    861         elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
    862             # Add key to exclusions

KeyError: 'TIME_MTD'
```

Comment: maybe have a look into `seaborn`. maybe [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-make-a-grouped-boxplot-graph-in-matplotlib) helps ? you can skip the groupby, just define, `x`, `y` and `hue`

Comment: @Rabinzel it works and very clean, but then looks different to my other plots..

Comment: can you provide some more of your data ? at the moment I just see head and tail. Some data with different groups of robots including the other columns would be very helpful

Comment: `groupby.boxplot` has no argument `by`. run that code without that statement and see if it suits you